# Repeat Elements in NumPy Array Based on Sub-element's value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I need to repeat elements in the following numpy array **arr** in such a way that elements are repeated based on a sub-element's value. While performing repetitions, I would like to reset the 3rd value of an element to 1.

```
arr = np.array([[A, B, 1],
[B, C, 2],
[C, D, 3],
[D, E, 1]])
```

Required output:

```
[[A, B, 1],
[B, C, 1],
[B, C, 1],
[C, D, 1],
[C, D, 1],
[C, D, 1],
[D, E, 1]]
```

Below code works well, however it becomes very slow with large datasets i.e. ~500k length.

```
_arr = primary_auto.to_records()
pm_arr = np.empty((0,3))

for i in range(len(_arr)):
    for nr in range(_arr[i][2]):
        pm_arr = np.append(pm_arr, np.array([[_arr[i][0],_arr[i][1],1]]), axis = 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html), then assign `1`:

```
arr = np.array([['A', 'B', 1],
['B', 'C', 2],
['C', 'D', 3],
['D', 'E', 1]])

out = np.repeat(arr, arr[:, 2].astype(int), axis=0)
out[:, -1] = 1
```

Note that due to the strings, all the array will be strings, you need to convert to integer for `repeat`

Output:

```
array([['A', 'B', '1'],
       ['B', 'C', '1'],
       ['B', 'C', '1'],
       ['C', 'D', '1'],
       ['C', 'D', '1'],
       ['C', 'D', '1'],
       ['D', 'E', '1']], dtype='<U11')
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the answer by using numpy

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([["A", "B", 1],
["B", "C", 2],
["C", "D", 3],
["D", "E", 2]])
k = np.repeat(arr, arr[:, -1].astype(np.int32), 0)
k[:, -1] = 1
k
```

```
array([['A', 'B', '1'],
       ['B', 'C', '1'],
       ['B', 'C', '1'],
       ['C', 'D', '1'],
       ['C', 'D', '1'],
       ['C', 'D', '1'],
       ['D', 'E', '1'],
       ['D', 'E', '1']], dtype='<U11')
```

Comment: How is it different from what I suggested?

Comment: I didn't see your answer before I post it